# How to use(/enable) FN keys to adjust volume at my asus laptop?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, shortcut-keys, volume-control

I have an ASUS laptop (ASUS X53S series) and I want to adjust the volume by using the <kbd>FN</kbd> key and <kbd>F10</kbd> (mute), <kbd>F11</kbd> (vol down), <kbd>F12</kbd> (vol up).

Also <kbd>F9</kbd> key is not working as well(this is for enabling/disabling the touchpad).

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53507/asus-u30sd-fn-keys-f9-f12-do-not-work) question but didn't see any solution.

All the other FN buttons seem to work(changing brightness,turning off display,switching off wifi).

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Have you tried going to Keyboard Shortcuts and set the desired as a shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with my ASUS K53E.

```
sudo apt-get install git

git clone git://git.iksaif.net/acpi4asus-dkms.git

cd acpi4asus-dkms 

make 

sudo make install

sudo modprobe asus-nb-wmi
```

After every kernel update the above will be erased and you will need to re-do it every time until it is included in a kernel version at a later stage. To make it easier create a .deb package which will be easier to install.

```
sudo apt-get install debhelper 

cd acpi4asus-dkms 

dpkg-buildpackage

sudo dpkg -i [newly-created-package].deb

sudo modprobe asus-nb-wmi
```

[source](http://blog.zasekoj.com/2011/07/16/enable-global-keys-hot-keys-in-ubuntu-on-asus-k53/)

I have a little different computer though; mine is a K53E and yours is an X53S, so I can't guarantee that it'll work.

Comment: This worked great :D thanks a lot! We do have the same motherboard ;)

Comment: I have noticed that F9 button (toggle touchpad) is not working. Any workaround for that?

Comment: `fatal: unable to connect to git.iksaif.net:`

Comment: If it's dkms we should be able to use dkms installation so that it automatically updates itself when there's a kernel update.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me... I was previously a Mac user and this confused me... it appears as though you have to hold down the Function Key on the bottom right while pushing the vol buttons in order for them to adjust up or down.

Comment: The text in the question indicates the user *is* holding down the <fn> key.

Answer (score -2):

If you press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button at the bottom left corner of your keypad, next to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button, and press <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> while you're at it, you'll be able to control your volume on the keypad.

So it's:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> → volume decreases,
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> → volume increases.

Comment: The body question indicates that the OP is using these keys.