# Fn keys and card reader not working in Asus k55

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, asus, sd-card

I am using ubuntu 12.04 in my new Asus K55 (Intel® Chief River Chipset HM76). It works pretty well but the SD card reader is not recognized, and the Fn keyboard keys are not working. I have followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63734/how-to-use-enable-fn-keys-to-adjust-volume-at-my-asus-laptop) but it does not help.

Can you help me? 
Thanks.

Here is the lspci output (for the not recognized card reader):

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1058 (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer kernels (the 3.5.x included in Ubuntu 12.10) solve the FN Keys problem.
However, the SD card module requires to be loaded.
As @Marco says, it can be done following  [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the card reader problem has already been solved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876

In my case it worked just downloading and installing the package, after a reboot, but you might prefer to follow the full procedure.

From the information you provided, we have the same operating system, motherboard and card reader, so I hope this solution will work for you, too.

About the Fn-keys problem, it's a different issue and I honestly don't know the solution. If someone else will find it, I hope they'll give you (us) an answer :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Like you said the card reader problem has been fixed :)