# Some of my Fn keys no longer work after may 8th updates

Tags: 12.04, function-keys

i seem to have the same issue described here
[FN keys F9 - F12 do not work on an Asus U30sd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53507/fn-keys-f9-f12-do-not-work-on-an-asus-u30sd) 
and it's happened before while running 12.04 beta but im currently running stable and it seems an update that was pushed on or around may 8th has messed up my Fn keys (just the f9-f12 ones, everything else is good)

my issue is that updating to the latest everything hasnt solved my issue but rather caused it
during the updates that happened that day i was asked (and hardly payed attention) if a config file should be replaced with default or kept as modified - i replaced with default, but im honestly not sure what config file it was

in Ubuntu software center i can go to history and choose updates and see what and when and maybe get some sort of list here if it helps, but i would imagine everyone running ubuntu saw the same updates that day (assuming they did updates that day)

for reference i am running an asus 1215n

Comment: well i just tried (on a whim) removing ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates and that seems to have worked

seems somehow the nvidia drivers jack up fn keys on some rigs

i'll add this as "answer my own question" after my 8 hour restriction passes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i just tried (on a whim) removing ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates and that seems to have worked

seems somehow the nvidia drivers jack up fn keys on some rigs